# Why is the following table in the 2nd normal form?

Tags: database, database-normalization

Here`s my table in the 1. Normal Form with the Primary Keys Student_ID and Course_Nr:

[image]

Here's my table in the 2. Normal Form: 
[image]

For a table to be in the 2nd normal form, it should NOT have partial dependency.

But the column Teacher in the student table is dependat on the column Co.Nr (Course Nr). 
Shouldn't that be in a seperate table (Course Nr# | Teacher) as well?

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. If you give an image, include a legend/key/explanation. Show the steps of your work following your textbook, with justification--we want to check your work but not redo it & we need your choices when an algorithm allows them & otherwise we can't tell you where you went wrong (or right). See hits googling 'stackexchange homework'.

Comment: Eg: It is not so that "For a table to be in the 2nd normal form, it should NOT have partial dependency." Why aren't you quoting & using the definition of 2NF? Eg: You don't even mention FDs re your decomposition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of Second Normal Form requires that in the relation schema no non-prime attribute should be dependent on a proper subset of any candidate key.

In the second relation schema the only candidate key is `StudentId`, and since the attribute `Teacher` depends on `CourseNumber`, which is not part of any candidate key, the definition is respected and the relation schema is in Second Normal Form.

Obviously there is a redundancy since the relation is not in Third Normal Form (3NF), and should be normalized.

In fact, the Second Normal Form is not considered important any more, and it is described just for historical reason, since all the normalization techniques aim to bring the relation schemas *at least* in the Third Normal Form or in the Boyce-Codd Normal Forms. This is so true that there are no formal algorithms to bring a relation schema in Second Normal Form, while there are algorithms for Third and Boyce-Codd Normal Forms.

Comment: Thank you, now I get it